# Javascript Calculation - If Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I would like to display a different option for different choices.

- If `MenuNo1 (textinput)` equal either `1,2,3,4 or 5` - then the value of `menuPrice1` should be `R70.00`.
- If `MenuNo1(textinput)` equal either `8,9,12` - then the value of `menuPrice1` should be `R85.00`.
- If `MenuNo1 (textinput)` equal `11` - then the value of `menuPrice1` should be `R105.00`.

I have tried doing it this way: However nothing appears in the `MenuPrice1` field? There are also no errors in the console.

```
function calcMenu(form) {
    var MenuPrice1 = (+form.MenuPrice1.value);
    var MenuNo1 = (+form.MenuNo1.value);

    if ([1,2,3,4,5].indexOf(+form.MenuNo1.value) != -1) {
        MenuPrice1.value = "70";
    } 
    else if ([8,9,12].indexOf(+form.MenuNo1.value) != -1) {
        MenuPrice1.value = "85";
    }
    else if (+form.MenuNo1.value == 11)  {
        MenuPrice1.value = "105";
   } 
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="quote" action="" method="get">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            jQuery('#quote').change(function() {
                doTotal(this)
            });
        });
        // ]]>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            jQuery('#quote').change(function() {
                calcMenu(this)
            });
        });
        // ]]>
    </script>
    <table width="532" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0.5">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" width="70">
                <div align="center">
                    Date
                </div></th>
                <th scope="col" width="158">
                <div align="center">
                    Amount of Delegates ½ Day Conference @ R 240 pp
                </div></th>
                <th width="112">
                <div align="center">
                    Amount of Delegates Full Day Conference @ R 260 pp
                </div></th>
                <th width="112">
                <div align="center">
                    Menu No
                </div></th>
                <th width="112">
                <div align="center">
                    Price pp for Menu (1-7: R70, 8-10 R85, 11: R105, 12: R85)
                </div></th>
                <th width="134">
                <div align="center">
                    Total for the day
                </div></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="date1" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="halfday1" size="15" maxlength="10" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="fullday1" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="MenuNo1" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="MenuPrice1" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="total1" size="15" />
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="date2" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="halfday2" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="fullday2" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="MenuNo2" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="MenuPrice2" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="total2" size="15" />
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="date3" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="halfday3" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="fullday3" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="MenuNo3" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="MenuPrice3" size="15" />
                </div></td>
                <td>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="total3" size="15" />
                </div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think that the calcMenu function is getting called in your case. Have you tried triggering it on anything other than '#quote'.change() event?

Comment: There's no 'change' event associated with a `<form>`.

Comment: @legendofawesomeness no, I have not tried that. The first function (doTotal) works this way, so I just copied what was used there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `var MenuPrice1 = (+form.MenuPrice1.value);` and are doing `MenuPrice1.value =` later on.

Also there is a cleaner way to do this that would make it easier to maintain in the future too.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8q7Fh/3

```
var prices = [
    {
        values: [1,2,3,4,5],
        price: 'R70.00'
    },
    {
        values: [8,9,12],
        price: 'R85.00'
    },
    {
        values: [11],
        price: 'R105.00'
    }
];

function calcMenu(form)
{
    var i, searchValue = parseInt(form.MenuNo1.value);
    form.MenuPrice1.value = '';

    for (i in prices)
    {
        if ($.inArray(searchValue, prices[i].values) != -1)
        {
            form.MenuPrice1.value = prices[i].price;
        }
    }
}
```

**Notes:** You are currently missing prices for when the values are either 6, 7 and 10. For now I've set it so that it will clear the value in the MenuPrice if it cannot find a definite price. Something to think about!

Comment: you are a lifesaver ! thank you very very kindly for your help.  I will include values for 6,7 and 10 also, thank you so much  This is a much better way of doing it :)

Comment: i would like the functions 'doTotal' and 'calcMenu' to calculate as the input field is updated (ie 'onKeyup) ?

Would I need to add this line to each of the input fields in order to achieve this:
document.getElementById("fullday1").onkeyup = dototal;
document.getElementById("halfday1").onkeyup = dototal;
document.getElementById("SingleRooms1").onkeyup = dototal;
etc? or is there a better way?

Comment: I have that inside `jQuery('#quote').change(function() {` ?